# How to translate belongs-to relationship in voyager laravel admin

Tags: laravel, translation, relationship, belongs-to, voyager

I am using voyager admin laravel that includes its own translations table and I have two tables `categories` and `products` that have a relationship, each product belongs to a category. Now when I fill products data and switch between languages `category` field doesn't change, it shows me always the default language.
any help?

Comment: Show Us Your code

Comment: There is no code !! it is `voyager admin` .. all I did is follow instructions of how to add languages tab by adding this simple code `use Translatable;
    protected $translatable = ['title', 'description', 'warranty'];` in Product model.

Answer (score 0):

In the view use the getTranslatedAttribute() method.

For example you list your products in foreach then use the following:

```
$product->category->getTranslatedAttribute('category_name', 'current_lang', 'fallback_lang')
```

category is the relationship (category() in the model).

That's it.